# Hi, im making 2048 using python and a graphics library and need some assistance

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, 2048

i'm using python and need to use an array to make 2048.

i am trying to figure out how to make the mechanism to create the moving of numbers in an array to remove the zero's and add two of the same number up. I've looked online but can't find anything.

Please could someone help me,
thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: This question is to broad. If yo uhave a specific issue in your code please share your code and any error and also what your expectation of the code is

Comment: You should start by looking at a few GUI libraries in Python.

Comment: I think you should start learning pyqt5 for example